# more tables created when create a new site

Tags: multisite, table, read-more, customization

Can someone suggest me an idea on this?

I am using Wordpress MU. And as per my requirement every user who register on main site will have a sub-site for them. And it is working correctly.

I noticed that whenever a new site is created it is creating few tables in the database as like wp_2_post, wp_2_postmeta and so on. **Whenever a new site is created, it is creating about 9 new tables in my database**.

**If i have 1000 users in my site, then will it create about 9000 new tables in my database?**

I will be having lot more users with my site.

So, can someone tell me is this right? Can i have this much of tables in my database? Or can i do anything else to avoid this? **Is there any other way to avoid this.?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behavior, and no, there is nothing you can do about it in a multi-site setup. But that's usually not a problem; disk space is cheap.

Maybe you could run a workaround with a single-site installation and rewrite rules to map subdomains to URLs like `/author/post-name/`. But that sounds like a collsion magnet; so I wouldn't recommend it.